# blank email bodies on exchange 2010 / outlook 2010

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2010

We are experiencing random blank email bodies on email sent between internal users on
Exchange 2010 sp1 rollup pack 3  and clients using outlook 2010 sp 1  on windows 7 with latest patches.
The same email sent to different users is correctly received by everyone but one single user (it happens randomly on different users).
In outlook the user can see headers (Sender, Receiver, subject, date, etc) but the body is completely blank.

We already tried with no luck:

- disabling antivirus.
- setting outlook email compose setting to rtf.
- deleting and recreating profiles and also disable cached mode on profiles.

Any suggestion would be welcome.

Comment: You tried Outlook in online mode, so I think I already know the answer, but could you humour me and see if the message is blank in OWA too?

Comment: You tried disabling antivirus where (Client or server)? Things like this are always antivirus. (disclaimer: not *always*).

Comment: The message is blank in owa too, we have only client side antivirus (AVG or avast ) we tried to disable it but same problem

Comment: I'm having the same issue, it's nearly identical. 2010 setup, users can see everything but the body, and it is always visible in OWA, always. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: *Is* blank in OWA, or *was* blank?  Try closing Outlook and keep only OWA open; send another message and see if it has a body in OWA.  If Outlook has already done something to the body of the message and sync'ed that change back, then you won't see the body in OWA either.

Comment: I've had the same problem here, never found a solution. If I go to Actions and View In Browser it's also visible. If I viewed the source it looked like something was mangling the HTML and changing some of the characters (although I can't remember what now). I guess Outlook is having a problem rendering the malformed HTML. We use McAfee and disabling the Outlook Add-In doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I had a client that was having the exact same issue.... OWA would show the body of the message but Outlook's message body was stripped out. With a little research and some googling skill I found and (successfully tested) that if you disable the Outlook AVG Add-in the problem goes away.